# Using SQL to make calculation based on some given criteria

Tags: php, sql, algorithm, sorting

In one of the examination applications I built, I am yet to figure out on a way to come up with an SQL statement to make this task possible. Our country's grading system requires only 7 subjects to be counted. In those subjects, all languages are compulsory(labelled lang in the pictorial demonstration). 2 of the best sciences are counted(labelled sci). One humanity(labelled hum). The 7th subject may be a technical subject(labelled tech), a science or a humanity depending on which has the best marks. For example, the student in the given table would have marks from MAT,ENG,KISW,PHY,CHEM,HIST and BST counted. I wrote PHP code utilizing arrays and it's taking up just too much memory and time which makes me fear it will bring the server to a halt. Take a look at the code below,

```
function calculatePointsB($adm,$term,$class,$year,$exam){
global $db;

$points=array(
    "A"=>12,
    "A-"=>11,
    "B+"=>10,
    "B"=>9,
    "B-"=>8,
    "C+"=>7,
    "C"=>6,
    "C-"=>5,
    "D+"=>4,
    "D"=>3,
    "D-"=>2,
    "E"=>1
);
$choices=array();
$countable=array();
$monitor=array();
$grades=array();

$common_query_all=$db->prepare("SELECT marks,subject,sub_cat FROM averaged_marks WHERE adm_no=? AND sub_cat=? AND term=? AND class=? AND year=?");
$common_query_sp=$db->prepare("SELECT marks,subject,sub_cat FROM exmarks WHERE adm_no=? AND sub_cat=? AND term=? AND class=? AND year=? AND e_type=?");
//languages first
$langs=array();
if($exam=="All") {
    $getlang = $common_query_all;
    $getlang->execute(array($adm, "lang", $term, $class, $year));
}else{
    $getlang = $common_query_sp;
    $getlang->execute(array($adm, "lang", $term, $class, $year,$exam));
}
while($rst=$getlang->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if($rst['marks']!=null) {
        $langs[$rst['subject']] = $rst['marks'];
        $grades[$rst['subject']]=$points[$rst['grade']];
        $countable[$rst['subject']] = $rst['marks'];
        array_push($monitor,$rst['sub_cat']);
    }else continue;
} unset($rst);

//sciences
$sciences=array();
if($exam=="All") {
    $getlang = $common_query_all;
    $getlang->execute(array($adm, "sci", $term, $class, $year));
}else{
    $getlang = $common_query_sp;
    $getlang->execute(array($adm, "sci", $term, $class, $year,$exam));
}
while($rst=$getlang->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if($rst['marks']!=null) {
        $sciences[$rst['subject']] = $rst['marks'];
        array_push($monitor,$rst['sub_cat']);
    }else continue;
}unset($rst);
arsort($sciences);

//humanities
$humanities=array();
if($exam=="All") {
    $getlang = $common_query_all;
    $getlang->execute(array($adm, "hum", $term, $class, $year));
}else{
    $getlang = $common_query_sp;
    $getlang->execute(array($adm, "hum", $term, $class, $year,$exam));
}
while($rst=$getlang->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if($rst['marks']!=null) {
        $humanities[$rst['subject']] = $rst['marks'];
        array_push($monitor,$rst['sub_cat']);
    }else continue;
}unset($rst);
arsort($humanities);

//technicals
$technic=array();
if($exam=="All") {
    $getlang = $common_query_all;
    $getlang->execute(array($adm, "tech", $term, $class, $year));
}else{
    $getlang = $common_query_sp;
    $getlang->execute(array($adm, "tech", $term, $class, $year,$exam));
}
while($rst=$getlang->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if($rst['marks']!=null) {
        $technic[$rst['subject']] = $rst['marks'];
        $choices[$rst['subject']] = $rst['marks'];
    }else continue;
}unset($rst);
arsort($technic);

//add optional subjects to choices array
$iteration=0;
foreach($humanities as $sub => $value){
    $iteration++;
    if($iteration >1 && $iteration <= 3){
        $choices[$sub]=$value;
    }elseif($iteration==1){
        $countable[$sub]=$value;
        if($exam=="All") {
            $grades[$sub] = $points[getgradeinSub($adm, $sub, $term, $class, $year)];
        }else{
            $grades[$sub] = $points[getgradeinSpSub($adm, $sub, $term, $class, $year,$exam)];
        }
    }
}unset($humanities);

$iteration=0;
foreach($sciences as $sub => $value){
    $iteration++;
    if($iteration > 2 && $iteration <= 3){
        $choices[$sub]=$value;
    }elseif($iteration<=2){
        $countable[$sub]=$value;
        if($exam=="All") {
            $grades[$sub] = $points[getgradeinSub($adm, $sub, $term, $class, $year)];
        }else{
            $grades[$sub] = $points[getgradeinSpSub($adm, $sub, $term, $class, $year,$exam)];
        }
    }
}unset($sciences);
arsort($choices);

//get required and view the required number
//count number of keys
$count_compasory=array_count_values($monitor);
if($count_compasory['lang']==3 && $count_compasory['sci']>=2 && $count_compasory['hum']>=1){
    $remaining=7-count($countable);
    $iteration=0;
    foreach($choices as $sub => $value){
        $iteration++;
        if($iteration <= $remaining){
            $countable[$sub]=$value;
            if($exam=="All") {
                $grades[$sub] = $points[getgradeinSub($adm, $sub, $term, $class, $year)];
            }else{
                $grades[$sub] = $points[getgradeinSpSub($adm, $sub, $term, $class, $year,$exam)];
            }
        }
    }
    unset($choices);
    unset($countable);
    unset($monitor);
    unset($langs);
    unset($sciences);
    unset($humanities);
    unset($points);

    return array_sum($grades);
}
else unset($choices);
unset($countable);
unset($monitor);
unset($langs);
unset($sciences);
unset($humanities);
unset($grades);
unset($points);

return null;}
```

A good programmer would consider this some bad practice. Is there a way to write an SQL statement for that? Getting a solution to the problem would be a breakthrough. A picture of the table is attached below.
[image: Sample Table]

Comment: Providing us with a sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some data (of the one student) would greatly help in answering this.
Seems to me this should be solvable with one select query with a couple of inner joins on the same table

Comment: What's your DBMS? Should be a simple task if it supports Analytical Functions like `ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: @Jester, here is the SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b80692

Comment: @dnoeth, am using mysql

Comment: Mysql is the almost the only DBMS which doesn't support Analytic Functions. Next question: do you need to run this for a single or multiple students?

Comment: @dnoeth, multiple students in order to create rank. But if i can manage to do the task for a single student, that will be a major step

Comment: Please give your question a title that actually describes the problem.

Comment: @m69, I have changed it. I hope it fits appropriately. Thanks for the suggestion  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best i could come up with in the short time i have, i took the same approach as @GarethParker except for the last mark you need quite a bit more.

You can try it on the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b80692/6)

```
(SELECT *
FROM averaged_marks
WHERE sub_cat='lang'
ORDER BY marks DESC)             #This select retrieves all 'lang' marks
UNION
(SELECT *
FROM averaged_marks
WHERE sub_cat='sci'
ORDER BY marks DESC
LIMIT 2)             #This select retrieves the highest 2 'sci' marks
UNION
(SELECT *
FROM averaged_marks
WHERE sub_cat='hum'
ORDER BY marks DESC
LIMIT 1)             #This select retrieves the highest 1 'hum' marks
UNION
(SELECT *            #This select retrieves the highest mark of the leftovers
FROM averaged_marks
WHERE averaged_marks.id NOT IN (     #This NOT IN contains the same select as above to get the first 6 marks and to make sure the 7th is not one of them.
    SELECT temp.id
    FROM
        ((SELECT averaged_marks.id
        FROM averaged_marks
        WHERE sub_cat='lang'
        ORDER BY marks DESC)
        UNION
        (SELECT averaged_marks.id
        FROM averaged_marks
        WHERE sub_cat='sci'
        ORDER BY marks DESC
        LIMIT 2)
        UNION
        (SELECT averaged_marks.id
        FROM averaged_marks
        WHERE sub_cat='hum'
        ORDER BY marks DESC
        LIMIT 1)
        ) AS temp)
ORDER BY marks DESC
LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: It worked as I expected. Am truly impressed and grateful for the time you took on it especially the section where you get the 7th  mark. You totally cracked what I was looking for. Cheers!

Comment: glad i could help :) if you need some mysql query help again sometime feel free to tag me ^^

Comment: Thanks again..I have a question. Could my MySQL version be having a bug?I am using MySQL 5.7 and when i run the query, it grabs the 7th subject from another admission number and selects a language too(lang). My table has about 5610 records. What could be the problem?

Comment: I just added 'AND adm_no=1' in each query to narrow down to a single student.

Comment: it should work i think if you limit it to one admission number in all the subqueries, double check if you haven't missed one? (probably in the last union) Also if you want it for all students you can do that in one query using `GROUP_CONCAT` and a join i think. That way you only do one request to the database.

Comment: I did that to all subqueries :). Take a look at the paste_bin -> http://pastebin.com/xzw6MkWf

Comment: no you didn't ;) you need to add an `AND adm_no = ` after the `NOT IN` clause.` check here: https://www.diffchecker.com/uvk07hql to see the difference

Comment: It finally worked. I salute you. Best regards. I will tag you in case of any questions. Thank you, Jester.

Comment: No problem! Good luck on the project and maybe till some other time!

Answer (score 0):

Without having test data to run against, and being unwilling to create my own, I'm hesitant to craft usable SQL, but it sounds like what you want might be the `UNION` operator. You can join the results of multiple SQL queries together with it. So you can have your different conditions and merely union them. Again, the below SQL is only an example, and it might not work, you may have to tweak it yourself

```
SELECT * FROM exmarks WHERE sub_cat='lang'
UNION
SELECT * FROM exmarks WHERE sub_cat='sci' ORDER BY mark DESC LIMIT 2
UNION
SELECT * FROM exmarks WHERE sub_cat='hum' ORDER BY mark DESC LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM exmarks WHERE sub_cat NOT IN ('lang', 'sci', 'hum') ORDER BY mark DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The last union is incorrect. it should take the highest one which hasn't been taken yet. so it could be from 'lang', 'sci', 'hum'. in his example it just doesn't happen to be the case.